# IOException: Failed to Move File / Directory from 'Temp/StagingArea/Data' to 'Temp/StagingArea\assets\bin\Data'

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

My project works very well but when I made the APK file, the error appears:

> IOException: Failed to Move File / Directory from 'Temp/StagingArea/Data' to 'Temp/StagingArea\assets\bin\Data'.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Maybe is better if you show your directory structure?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! This is my fault. Because the name of the file is "Y - Yen_00000" and my project is too heavy.